# SQL query join with multiple conditions & multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want combine 3 tables in one query with join

Table A - `Employee_Data`

| Employee_ID | Job_Title |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | Eng. |
| BBB | Eng. |
| CCC | Office |

Table B - `Training_List`

| Job_Title | Training_Item |
| --- | --- |
| Eng. | Working Safety |
| Eng. | Working awareness |
| Eng. | Job Training |
| Office | Working awareness |
| Office | Office Rules |

Table C - `Training_Record`

| Employee_ID | Training_Item | Training_Date | Training_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Working Safety | 2023/06/10 | 70 |
| AAA | Working Safety | 2023/06/14 | 80 |
| BBB | Working Safety | 2023/06/14 | 80 |
| CCC | Office Rules | 2023/06/11 | 90 |

This is my query string

```
SELECT 
    A.Employee_ID, A.Job_Title,
    B.Training_Item,
    C.Training_Date, C.Traing_Score 
FROM 
    (Employee_Data A 
LEFT JOIN 
    Training_List B ON A.Job_Title = B.Job_Title) 
LEFT JOIN 
    Training_Record C ON A.Employee_ID = C.Employee 
                      AND C.Training_Item = B.Training_Item
```

But it's not working.

All employee cross all training item & merge Training record with last Training Date & Score

If there have no training record return NA

Result should be:

| Employee_ID | Job_Title | Training_Item | Training_Date | Training_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Eng. | Working Safety | 2023/06/14 | 80 |
| AAA | Eng. | Working awareness | NA | NA |
| AAA | Eng. | Job Training | NA | NA |
| BBB | Eng. | Working Safety | 2023/06/14 | 80 |
| BBB | Eng. | Working awareness | NA | NA |
| BBB | Eng. | Job Training | NA | NA |
| CCC | Office | Working awareness | NA | NA |
| CCC | Office | Office Rules | 2023/06/11 | 90 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short normalize these tables.  Then this would be a simple query.  When I have a complicated query I like to build it in pieces which simplifies things.  It happens we can use EmployeeID and Job_Title as Temporary primary keys, but don't try to set up the cascading updates and deletes:

[image]

Going from right to left, we can get the first two columns we need from the relationship between Employee_Data and Training_List.

[image]

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Employee_ID      |        Training_Item        |     Job_Title      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AAA                   | Working Safety              | Eng.               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AAA                   | Working awareness           | Eng.               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AAA                   | Job Training                | Eng.               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BBB                   | Working Safety              | Eng.               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BBB                   | Working awareness           | Eng.               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BBB                   | Job Training                | Eng.               |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CCC                   | Working awareness           | Office             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CCC                   | Office Rules                | Office             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Conceptually, I'm first making a subquery to get the information I need out of the Training_list, particularly Training_Item, and into Employee_Data so then I have everything I need before using Employee_ID and Training_Item to get the right Training_Records.

[image]

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Employee_ID     |       Training_Item       |    Training_Date     |     Training_Score      |         t          |         S          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AAA                 | Working Safety            |            6/10/2023 |                      70 | 6/10/2023          | 70                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AAA                 | Working Safety            |            6/14/2023 |                      80 | 6/14/2023          | 80                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AAA                 | Working awareness         |                      |                         | NA                 | NA                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AAA                 | Job Training              |                      |                         | NA                 | NA                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BBB                 | Working Safety            |            6/14/2023 |                      80 | 6/14/2023          | 80                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BBB                 | Working awareness         |                      |                         | NA                 | NA                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BBB                 | Job Training              |                      |                         | NA                 | NA                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CCC                 | Working awareness         |                      |                         | NA                 | NA                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CCC                 | Office Rules              |            6/11/2023 |                      90 | 6/11/2023          | 90                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the two relationships between Query2 and Training_Records are darkened.  This is because we wanted to show missing values so I clicked them to setup left-joins by choosing to show all values from Query2.  S and t are shown by request but do not make such a change in the query.  Instead use the same code to display "NA" in the controls attached to the form or report.  S & t have been implicitly cast to strings.

Comment: Thanks for your step by step help
It's work in ms-access

But i need query i another app
I change my database to ms sql and then it's working
anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  A.Employee_ID,
  A.Job_Title,
  B.Training_Item,
  C.Training_Date AS Training_Date,
  C.Training_Score AS Training_Score
FROM
  Employee_Data A
  LEFT JOIN Training_List B ON A.Job_Title = B.Job_Title
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      Employee_ID,
      Training_Item,
      Training_Date,
      Training_Score
    FROM
      Training_Record R
    WHERE
      (Employee_ID, Training_Date) IN (
        SELECT
          Employee_ID,
          MAX(Training_Date) AS Latest_Training_Date
        FROM
          Training_Record
        GROUP BY
          Employee_ID, Training_Item
      )
  ) C ON A.Employee_ID = C.Employee_ID AND B.Training_Item = C.Training_Item;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
But it's still "Join expression not supported" in ms-access
There have any rules in multi left join with multi conditions?
"ON A.Employee_ID = C.Employee_ID AND B.Training_Item = C.Training_Item"